# Await and return all resolved promise values together within an object

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have an object we'll call `pages` where the value for each key (`typeOne`, `typeTwo`, etc...) is an array of objects - and a key in that object called `formData` is a pending Promise. I'd like to essentially update the `pages` object such that each `formData` key is the promise's resolved value.

I have successfully been able to do so by essentially mapping through each of the values in `pages` - however, this is slow because seems to await and resolve each `type*`'s array set before moving to the next set, if that makes any sense.

```js
(async () => {
  let pages = {
    typeOne: [
      {
        formData: Promise<pending>
      },
      ...
    ],
    ...
  }
  ...
  for (type of _.keys(pages)) {
    pages[type] = await Promise.all(pages[type].map(async page => {
      page.formData = await page.formData;
      return page;
    })); 
  }
  ...
  // do stuff with pages
})()
```

Is there clean way to write this such that it awaits all Promises at once, then replaces the promises with the resolved values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *two* `Promise.all`s; one to iterate over the keys, and another nested one to iterate over each page:

```
  const resolvedPages = {};
  await Promise.all(Object.entries(pages).map(([key, typeArr]) =>
    Promise.all(typeArr.map(
        // Wait for each individual Promise to resolve, then map to a new object
        ({ formData }) => formData.then(({ resolveValue }) => ({ formData: resolveValue }))
      )
      .then((resolvedArrOfObjs) => {
        resolvedPages[key] = resolvedArr;
      })
    )
  ))
```

No need for an iteration library.

Make sure not to implicitly create global variables, like with `for (type of` - that'll pollute the global scope or throw errors in strict mode.